# MATLAB Loop error when adding noise function

Tags: matlab

One of the tasks for my assignment is to add an appropriate noise function to the following equation:

```
x = A*(1+a1*E)*sin(w*(1+a2*E)*t+y)+ a3*E
```

We must then plot the noise function vs. time as well as the original function with the noise added. I have asked the professor if a random number generator between -1 and 1 will suffice and he has agreed. I have the following code so far:

```
t  = 0:0.1:6.5;
A  = 2;
a1 = 2;
a2 = 4;
a3 = 3;
w  = 1;
y  = 2;

for i=1:length(t)
    E(i)  = random('unif', -1, 1, 1, 1);
    x(i) = A*(1+a1*E(i))*sin(w*(1+a2*E(i))*t+y)+ a3*E(i);
    i=i+1;
end
plot(t,E)
figure
stem(t,x)
```

I keep getting the following error In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must
be the same.

```
Error in Try1 (line 58)
    x(i) = A*(1+a1*E(i))*sin(w*(1+a2*E(i))*t+y)+ a3*E(i);
```

I don't understand the error because the E is just one number.

Any help appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that `E` is just one number, but you're multiplying by `t`, which is not just one number - it's an array. I think you meant to multiply by `t(i)`.

```
                              here------v
x(i) = A*(1+a1*E(i))*sin(w*(1+a2*E(i))*t(i)+y)+ a3*E(i);
```